# Find points on a plane with given distance to point

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, numerical-linear-algebra

Given the equation of a plane $P$:
$$-x - 2y + 2z = -5$$
and a point $Q$:
$$(2, -3, 0)$$

How do you find four points on $P$ which have a distance of 3√10 units away from from $Q$?

I tried using the pythagorean theorem with the point on $P$ that is closest to $Q$ but I haven't really been able to get anywhere with that.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Some users won't even read your question if is not properly formated.

Comment: You can find the equation of sphere with that point as center and distance as radius. And the intersection between your plane and this sphere is what you are lokking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.  The point $K$ on the plane which is closest to $Q$ is

$K = Q - d \dfrac{N}{\| N \|} $

where

$ N = \langle -1, -2, 2 \rangle $

and

$ d = \dfrac{ N \cdot Q + 5 }{\| N \|} = \dfrac{ -1(2) -2(-3) +2(0)+ 5 }{ 3 } = 3 $

So

$ K = (2, -3, 0) - \dfrac{3 (-1, -2, 2)}{3} = (3, -1, -2) $

The minimum distance $QK = 3 $, so the radius of the circle on which the required points lie is $ \sqrt{ (3 \sqrt{10})^2 - (3)^2 } = \sqrt{ 90 - 9 } = \sqrt{ 81} = 9 $

Now you need to generate two spanning vectors that are mutually orthogonal and also orthogonal to $N$.  One such vector is

$ U = \langle 2, -1, 0 \rangle $

Another vector is given by

$ V = N \times U = \langle -1, -2, 2 \rangle \times \langle 2, -1, 0 \rangle = \langle 2 , 4, 5 \rangle $

We need to normalize $U$ and $V$, so define

$ u = \dfrac{U}{\| U \| } = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \langle 2, -1, 0 \rangle $

and

$ v = \dfrac{V}{\| V \| } = \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{5}} \langle 2, 4, 5 \rangle $

Now the four desired points can be generated as follows

$ P_i = K + 9\cos(t_i) \ u + 9\sin(t_i) \ v , \ i = 1, 2, 3, 4 $

where the $\{ t_i \}$'s are any four distinct real numbers, for example, one could choose

$ t_1 = 0 , \ t_2 = \dfrac{\pi}{2} , \ t_3 = \pi , \ t_4 = \dfrac{3 \pi}{2} $

to generate four points that are equidistant from each other (corners of a square).